# Объяснение - что такое парсинг?

Tags: html, php, синтаксический-анализ

Всем привет. Часто слышу вот такую вещь, "я сделал парсинг такого то сайта" или еще что то.
Как это работает? что это такое??

Спасибо

Comment: Вы не нашли [информацию по этому вопросу][1] или не понимаете смысл написанного?

   [1]:https://www.google.com/search?q=парсинг+сайтов

Comment: Под парсингом традиционно понимается перевод информации из текстовой формы в структурированную. Например, из текста HTML в DOM.

Comment: Какого лешего? Вас забанили на википедии? Там есть статья по [теме][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Comment: спарсить сайт === программно стыбрить контент

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За трактовкой термина - в гугл. А скорее всего так говорят, когда достают с сайта автоматическим способом какие-то данные, часто даже всю хтмлку без обработки, что по сути парсингом вряд ли можно назвать. Ну а так - это целенаправленное копирование нужной информации с предварительным анализом источника и нахождения в нем блоков, несущих эту саму информацию. Например: выкачать с новостного сайта все содержимое блока с классом news вместе с метаинформацией (датой в дивке с классом date и т.д.).
Иногда для избавления от этой работы сервис предлагает API с которого эту инфу можно взять без лишних телодвижений.

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Получение и разбор (анализ) информации с какого-либо сайта в своё приложение и т.п. и использование её в каких-либо целях. Например, у тебя программа, которая конвертирует валюты. Чтобы сконвертировать тебе нужны курсы валют. Ты находишь сайт с курсами валют и парсишь(получаешь) их себе в программу.